# how to add a custom querystring parameter on Ajax call of AciTree jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, acitree

I am using a jQueryI want to send a custom querystring parameter along with node_id, e.g _type which is in json as shown below

```
[{
    "id":"2",    
    "label":"Title for folder",    
    "branch":[],    
    "inode":true,    
    "open":false,    
    "icon":"folder",    
    "_type":"library"
}]
```

I am trying with `ajaxhook` as shown below

```
ajaxHook: function (item, settings) {
    // the default implementation changes the URL by adding the item ID at the end    
    alert(this.itemData._type);    
    settings.url += (item ? this.getId(item) : '');    
}
```

I am unable to get my custom property `_type` using this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the correct way to do this :

```
  ajaxHook: function (item, settings) {
                    // the default implementation changes the URL by adding the item ID at the end
                    if (item != null) {
                        var ItemData = this.itemData(item);
                        settings.url += (item ? this.getId(item) : '') + '&type=' + ItemData._type;
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

this.itemData is an array, therefore or either you loop on it, or do something like:

```
alert(this.itemData[0]._type);
```